# Is it possible with ByteBuddy to intercept a method that is declared by an interface with an annotation?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I need to instrument all methods, which implement an interface that itself is annotated. Consider such an example:

```java
@WebService
interface HelloWorld {
  void hello();
}
class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {
  void hello() {...}
  void goodBye() {...}
}
```

Here I need to have an advice around `hello`, because it is declared by an interface with `@WebService` annotation. Is it possible to build such a ButeBuddy matcher?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the `ElementMatchers` class, you find a long row of predefined matchers, also such that deal with annotations. Do however know that annotations on interfaces are not inherited. You'd need to wrap the matcher in a `ElementMatchers.hasSuperType` to check the entire hierarchy.